# Hive Service Stops after few minutes automatically

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have setup hadoop and hive on aws ec2 server with 14.04 ubuntu, when i run a background process for hive after hadoop services the hive server stops working after some time, still facing the issue below is the given command

```
hive --service hiveserver2 &
```

Comment: Is it started successfully and then stop working ?. If it's stop working after some time, then there could be some run time issues. Please check the hive logs (/var/log/).

Comment: The `nohup` command could be what you are looking for... will solve all issues about SSH session disconnects.

Comment: please post logs

Comment: I have got some memory allocation error in site-yarn.xml